# Is there any shortcut to add current DateTime stamp snippet to c# file in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

This may be foolish, but i am looking for shortcut like F5 in notepad to add date time stamp, for simple summary task in c# files, for e.g.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Created By: Developer Name
        /// Created On: 12:08 PM 10/28/2013
        /// Pass HTML SELECT control and IsFirstOptionToRemove (optional) to find all its values and displayed text
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="selectControl"></param>
        /// <param name="IsFirstOptionToRemove"></param>
        /// <returns>retruns dictionary containing key value pairs of select control options. </returns>
```

i don't expect all these lines as snippet but can i have current date time stamp in my snippet. I didn't find a way to modify custom snippet dynamically.

Comment: IMHO, "Created by" and "Created on" is defined by the source code version control system (SVN, GIT...).

Comment: My experience is that having a timestamp in documentation is rarely useful. It's useful to know which version of an API first included a particular member, but that's a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet In fact, sometimes this info directly in code seems to be some kind of demonstration that something was done by the author and show everyone who did it!! I don't know if OP is a single developer or he's working in a small/large team, where SCVS works best to identify who did something. I find that better because leaves code comments for just documentation, who cares who did it when reading comments if it's a team!

Answer (score 2):

There's a macro-based solution described here:

http://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/articletype/articleview/articleid/62/net-commenting-macro.aspx

Basically, you make a macro like this:

```
 Sub CommentInitialsDate()
     DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "// [INSERT MY INITIALS HERE] " & Format(Date.Today, "yyyy-MM-dd") & " - "
 End Sub
```

And then you assign a shortcut key.